# How to completely remove Angular version

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a problem with Angular. I've installed version 13.0.0, but I need 13.3.6 or the latest from @13.

I did standard procedure:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall -g angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm cache verify
```

I had info with `ng version`:

> Your global Angular CLI version (13.3.6) is greater than your local version (13.0.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

I've downgraded nodejs, because I had not compatible node with version 13.

I've remove Angular once again - still this same problem.

I've removed folder:

```
C:\Users\USR\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular
```

then installed Angular and I still have problem with versions:

> Your global Angular CLI version (13.3.6) is greater than your local version (13.0.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.`

How to remove the `local` version or clear the angular totally and install it from scratch?

Comment: Your issue is the local version (of your project) of `@angular/cli` that is out-of-date.

Answer (score 0):

1. > I've installed version 13.0.0, but I need 13.3.6

   Why don`t u just set this in **package.json**? Update package.json
   and reinstall node_modules.
2. > Your global Angular CLI version (13.3.6) is greater than your local version (13.0.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

   As for global CLI version. I think its enough just to run

   ```
   npm i -g @angular/cli@13.0.4
   ```

   to make your local and global CLI versions equal.